# Combining string values from an array

Tags: java

I have created a loop that takes an int, turns it into a character array, and displays values based on the characters in the array. How can I print the values on the same line? In other words, instead of:

> value
>
> value
>
> value

I need:

> value value value

```
public static int getValue(int number) {
  final PrintStream ps = System.out;
  for (char c : Integer.toString(number).toCharArray())
    switch (c) {
    case '0':
      ps.println('a');
      break;
    case '1':
      ps.println('b');
      break;
    case '2':
      ps.println('c');
      break;
    // etc.
    }
```

Comment: Hint: Check why `println` is named how it is.

Answer (score 5):

Replace all but the last

```
System.out.println();
```

statements with

```
System.out.print();
```

It's the same thing, but without an added newline at the end.